# Cloud formation circular dependency firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have following CloudFormation template. Previous change sets've successfully created a kinesis stream and all listed roles. Now I would like to add a firehuse delivery stream. But my change set fails with `FAILED - Circular dependency between resources: [EventDeliveryStream]` message. Can anyone pls help what is wrong with my template?

Already applied resource templates:

```
   AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
    Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
    Description: XXX

    Resources:
      EventStream:
        Type: "AWS::Kinesis::Stream"
        Properties:
          Name: "event-stream"
          RetentionPeriodHours: 24
          ShardCount: 1

     KinesisReadOnlyAccessRole:
        Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
        Properties:
          RoleName: "kinesis-read-only-access-role"
          Path: "/"
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
            -
              Effect: "Allow"
              Principal:
                Service: "firehose.amazonaws.com"
              Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
          ManagedPolicyArns:
          - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonKinesisReadOnlyAccess"
      ElasticSearchRole:
        Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
        Properties:
          RoleName: "elastic-search-role"
          Path: "/"
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
            -
              Effect: "Allow"
              Principal:
                Service: "firehose.amazonaws.com"
              Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
          ManagedPolicyArns:
          - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonESFullAccess"
      FailedDataS3BucketRole:
        Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
        Properties:
          RoleName: "failed-data-s3-bucket-role"
          Path: "/"
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
            -
              Effect: "Allow"
              Principal:
                Service: "firehose.amazonaws.com"
              Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
          ManagedPolicyArns:
          - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
```

New resource template I would like to add:

```
     EventDeliveryStream:
        Type: "AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream"
        Properties:
          DeliveryStreamName: "kinesis-to-elastic"
          DeliveryStreamType: KinesisStreamAsSource
          KinesisStreamSourceConfiguration:
            KinesisStreamARN: !Ref EventStream
            RoleARN: !Ref KinesisReadOnlyAccessRole
          ElasticsearchDestinationConfiguration:
            DomainARN: "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:xxx:domain/xxx-data"
            RoleARN: !Ref ElasticSearchRole
            IndexName: "kinesis-events"
            TypeName: "object"
            IndexRotationPeriod: "NoRotation"
            RetryOptions:
              DurationInSeconds: "60"
            S3BackupMode: "FailedDocumentsOnly"
            BufferingHints:
              IntervalInSeconds: "60"
              SizeInMBs: "5"
            CloudWatchLoggingOptions:
              Enabled: true
              LogGroupName: "/aws/kinesisfirehose/event-stream-firehose"
              LogStreamName: "kinesis-to-elastic"
            S3Configuration:
              BucketARN:
                Ref: "arn:aws:s3:::etl-failed-data"
              RoleARN: !Ref FailedDataS3BucketRole
              Prefix: "firehose/"
              BufferingHints:
                IntervalInSeconds: "60"
                SizeInMBs: "5"
              CompressionFormat: "UNCOMPRESSED"
```

Comment: I am not sure why this sometimes happens, and sometimes does not, but essentially what has worked for me in the past is that you need to add the components in parts, so serverless can create the resource that you reference further down the code before it starts on the latter ones. So.. before you do anything with the new stream add the statement that creates it fully first, then sls deploy, then add your additional code and sls deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in invalid template

```
BucketARN:
   Ref: "arn:aws:s3:::etl-failed-data"
```

and the error message was completely misleading